# how to copy os.system('cat /var/log/dmesg') to a variable

Tags: python, linux, shell

```
import sys
import os

log = os.system('cat /var/log/demesg')
```

This code prints the file by running the shell script `cat /var/log/dmesg`.  However, it is not copied to the log. I want to use this data somewhere else or just print the data like print log.

How can I implement this?

Comment: See for example this thread of how to get output from shell commands:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-from-python-and-capturing-the-output

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply read from the file yourself:

```
with open('/var/log/dmesg') as logf:
    log = logf.read()
print(log)
```

Answer (score 2):

As an option, take a look at IPython.  Interactive Python brings a lot of ease of use tools to the table.

```
ipy$ log = !dmesg
ipy$ type(log)
 <3> IPython.utils.text.SList
ipy$ len(log)
 <4> 314
```

calls the system, and captures stdout to the variable as a String List.

Made for collaborative science, handy for general purpose Python coding too.  The web based collaborative Notebook (with interactive graphing, akin to Sage notebooks) is a sweet bonus feature as well, along with the ubiquitous support for parallel computing.

http://ipython.org

Answer (score 1):

To read input from a child process you can either use **fork**(), **pipe**() and **exec**() from the **os** module; or use the **subprocess** module